# vs 2015 Error adding entity data model

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio

I get the following error trying to add a new entity model. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot or fix this?

> An error occurred loading the entity data model tools package. failed
>   to load entity data model tools package. the result is -2147024894

Visual Studio 2015 Update 1
v14.0.24720.00

Entity Framework Nuget Package
v6.1.3

Microsoft .net 4.6.0

UPDATE
I tried installing this, it worked once and then after rebooting a couple days later no longer fixed the issue. It's back:
I was able to fix this by downloading the entity framework 6.x t4 templates and installing them from this: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/18a7db90-6705-4d19-9dd1-0a6c23d0751f?SRC=VSIDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get around this error by changing the framework from version 4.x to 4.5 on my project and then restarting visual studio. It took some tinkering but it appears this occurs because the Visual Studio 2015 Entity Model Package wizard is dependent on something in the 4.5 framework.